# On Click button UICollectionViewCell Width and Height Change

Tags: ios, button, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have `UIViewController`, inside using `UICollectionViewController` and Single Button, I want to change `UICollectionViewControllerCell` when On Click Button, like Height and Width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this once

```
[UIView transitionWithView:collectionView 
              duration:.5 
               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp 
            animations:^{

    //any animatable attribute here.
    cell.frame = CGRectMake(3, 14, 100, 100);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
  //whatever you want to do upon completion
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

implement the delegate for collection view

```
- (UICollectionViewTransitionLayout *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                        transitionLayoutForOldLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)fromLayout
                                           newLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)toLayout
```

and using IBAction to your button change the value for height and width.